Example of meson-python Cython package with src layout
I am having trouble finding a minimal example of a Cython project that uses meson-python for packaging and is set up using the "src layout" (as described here).
I have seen examples of meson-python projects, Cython projects, and src layout, but not one that includes all of these elements.
Can someone point me to one, or show how to set up the src layout directory structure, pyproject.toml file, and meson.build files to handle Cython?
I also will need a "tests" directory -- where does this go and how can it import the built package?

I was able to use meson-python, Cython, and src/ folder structure on a dummy project based on the C++ example on the Cython documentation. In short, you will need to use include_directories option in py.extension_module:
project('My Cython Project', 'cython')

py = import('python').find_installation()
dep_py = py.dependency()

py.extension_module(
    'rect',
    'src/rect.pyx',
    dependencies: dep_py,
    override_options : ['cython_language=cpp'],
    install: true,
    include_directories: ['src'],
)

For reference, the pyproject.toml looks like
[build-system]
build-backend = 'mesonpy'
requires = ['meson-python']

[project]
name = 'My-Cython-project'
version = '0.0.1'
readme = 'README.md'
requires-python = '>=3.9'

and my folder structure looks like
cython-mesonpy/
├── README.md
├── meson.build
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    ├── Rectangle.cpp
    ├── Rectangle.h
    ├── Rectangle.pxd
    └── rect.pyx

